# Anchor tag text

Tags: css, anchor

I have text on an anchor tag displaying over the center of an image. Is there a way to remove the text from the image in the CSS or HTML at all? I don't wanna just delete the text from the tag in the HTML outright.

```
<a title="mario" id="mario" href="#">Mario</a>
```

```
a {
    border: 5px solid black;
    padding: 140px 80px 135px 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Please write your code here, it will be easier for us to help.

Comment: Please share more details on what you already have, this might have multiple solutions depending on the HTML structure you have and the reasons why you want to make this change. Share your code in your question

Comment: If you're attempting this for SEO or something for an image as a link then instead just move your inner text to either/or the `title` attribute (which also acts as a tooltip) or the `aria-label` attribute. However, it's tough to help when we can't see your attempt.

Comment: try `text-indent: -9999px;`

Comment: `I don't wanna just delete the text from the tag in the HTML outright.` Why not?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. I added some of my code from the HTML and CSS.

Comment: @Gamester1118 I don't see any image on the code you provided, it's not clear what you're trying to do... What's the purpose of the image, why can't the link be in there? Why can't you just get rid of the anchor tag and leave just the image tag? Try to provide more info and more in you code sample

Answer (score -1):

you should add these properties

```
a {
  ...
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Therefore your `a` element styling will look like this

```
a {
    border: 5px solid black;
    padding: 140px 80px 135px 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```